# Use split to align equation and the operation which is applied

Tags: math-mode, split

I want to display an equation on multiple lines. I know that I can align multi-line equation with the `split` environment. But now I would like to align the equation by the equal sign and display at the end of the equation the applied operations like this:

```
3 * x = 15 | /3
x     = 5
```

So far I have this code, but I don't know which is the best way to align the applied operation.

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        U_{VS1} - I_{C} \cdot R_{1} &= U_{VS1} - I_{C} \cdot R_{2} \quad \lvert \, + I_{C} \cdot R_{2} \\
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`split` is the wrong tool for this: you need `alignedat`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
  &U_{VS1} - I_{C}R_{1} &&= U_{VS1} - I_{C}R_{2} \quad \lvert {} + I_{C} R_{2} \\
  &U_{VS1}              &&= U_{VS1}
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The trick is to have two pairs of right-left columns, using only the left aligned ones.

[image]